# HTML textarea default value does not visualise

Tags: html, textarea

I have a problem with textarea. I have set a default value to it in my HTML but it doesn't visualise. Here is a picture:

http://postimg.org/image/lbn5mwugv/

Also I use this textarea to save data to mongodb but even though with default value it is not saved , because it is read as empty when nothing is typed in(there is default value between  and )

It is generated from jade :

```
.userContainer
    .col-md-4
        img.profileImg(src="{{ identity.currentUser.profilePic }}" , width="50px" , height="50px")
        .profileData {{ identity.currentUser.firstName }} {{ identity.currentUser.lastName }}
        textarea.post-form.form-control(rows="4" , placeholder="Share to world of LinkMe", ng-model='activity.body')
        textarea.post-form.form-control#firstName(rows="4" , ng-model='activity.firstName') {{ identity.currentUser.firstName }}
        textarea.post-form.form-control#lastName(rows="4" , ng-model='activity.lastName') {{ identity.currentUser.lastName }}
        textarea.post-form.form-control#profilePic(rows="4" , ng-model='activity.profilePic') {{ identity.currentUser.profilePic }}
        a#post-btn.btn.btn-primary.pull-right(ng-click="addpost(activity)", href="/") Link
        br
        br
        br
        ul.noListStyle
            li(ng-repeat="post in activity | orderBy: '-date'")
                .postBody {{ post.body }} on {{ post.date | date: 'dd MMM h:mm'}} from {{ post.firstName }} {{ post.lastName }}
```

Comment: How do you set default value tor your text area?

Comment: Default value is set when you add a string (or something else) between the opening and closing bracket. For exmaple: <textarea>defaultfalue</textarea>

Comment: Include, in the question, code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I included the jade file which compilates to html